# wait for element to be enabled protratcor

Tags: selenium, protractor

Again, this question might be easy or already asked but i am not able to find any answer to this. All i get is to check if element is clickable but that is not working for me.
Is there any simple solution to wait for an element until it becomes enabled. I have set of dropdowns in my application and other dropdown get selectable only when value is selected in previous dropdown.
I tried below code but it is not working.

```
var element = element(by.css('[id*="uxSeries"] select'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element), 10000);
```

Error message i am getting:

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document

HTML for dropdown before it get enabled:

```
<select name="GalleryControl$uxSeries" onchange="OnChangeScript" id="uxSeries" disabled="disabled" style="width:215px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All Series</option>
        <option value="Value1">Option1</option>
        <option value="Value2">Option2</option>
        <option value="Value3">Option3</option>
        <option value="Value4">Option4</option>
        <option value="Value5">Option5</option>
    </select>
```

After i select value in my first dropdown, disabled="disabled" property goes away from dropdown.
Can i wait for browser until it is enabled or Disabled property is no more?

Comment: What is the selector of `element` in your example?

Comment: @FlorentB. I am selecting element by id.

Comment: I think tried locator is not correct, why are you not trying as `element(by.css("select#uxSeries"));` or `element(by.id("uxSeries"));`??

Comment: Is the *element* inside any other element in the DOM which also get visible/invisible conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

This exception occurred due to changing of element, as you are saying *I have set of dropdowns in my application and other dropdown get selectable only when value is selected in previous dropdown* means when it's getting enable, it changes their position or some attribute value may be `disabled` attribute become change that's why you're in trouble.

You should try first to wait until this element become stale from disabled state using [`protractor.ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf), then find again this element when it is in enable state as below :-

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

#find disabled select element first 
var disabledSelect = element(by.css("select#uxSeries[disabled='disabled']"));

#now wait until this becomes stale from disabled state
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(disabledSelect), 10000);

#now find enabled select element 
var enabledSelect = element(by.css("select#uxSeries"));

#now do your further steps
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Still same error stating `Failed: invalid element state
      (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)`